# Thermal Monocular live streaming

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, streaming, wireless-bridge

I have a AGM TM160 thermal monocular that creates its own ad hoc WiFi network. iOS and Android phones can use the T-Vision app to connect to this device and control all settings and view a live stream from the unit.

I would like to live stream this video or better yet be able to remote into a monocular’s WIFI from hundreds of miles away.

For example… I have a monocular set up deep in the woods. I have buried cables carrying Fiber gigabit to a WiFi router along with power. All of this is set up and working perfectly. But I need the ad hoc WiFi from the monocular to somehow connect to the wireless routers WiFi(probably impossible) or can I use a WiFi to either-net adapter to connect the ad hoc WiFi to a lan port on the router.

My objective is to either stream the monocular video live 24/7, or better yet remotely connect to the ad hoc monocular WiFi network from my main home in the city.

Again, both the city and woods location have AC power and High-speed internet. The Problem is… unlike a security camera that connects to a WiFi network, this thermal monocular creates its own ad hoc network requiring a cell phone to be in close (40 yards) proximity to it. I would like to bridge the distance and connect my cell to it from my city network and change the settings on it in real time. And of course view it.

Answer (score 0):

As nobody else is taking a shot at this...

The ad-hoc network is a separate WiFi network the moncular is broadcasting. You haven't specified what exactly is "router", but by the way you frame the question I assume it's a WiFi router. In that case it is bcasting its own WiFi network and no, you cannot connect one to the other. I'm also extremely suspicious about the possibility of using an Ethernet/Wifi adapter to connect to the ad-hoc - the router manufacturer's documentation would be the first place to check.

I've been racking my head around this for a couple of hours now. The easiest way might be to add a RasPi to where the router is, or directly to the cable. You could then connect the RasPi wirelessly to the monocular.

There are several options to run Android on RasPi such as LineageOS and EmteriaOS (source: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-android-lineageos/, but the linked LineageOS specifically states:

> The only feature missing from these builds of Android is support for hardware decoding and encoding of video. You may experience some slowdowns when trying to play video files through Android.

That said, although the LineageOS page dates from March 21, the OS itself is already 5 years old, so I'm pretty sure someone has taken a shot at tackling this specific problem. Also the page isn't exactly clear whether same applies to [EmteriaOS](https://emteria.com).

Comment: Yeah router is an Apple AirPort Extreme with WiFi, wan and lan ports. 

So you’re  saying,  load a RasPi with LineageOS connect it to the Monoculars WiFi and basically emulate a cell phone?  Then what do I do? Can I remote into the RasPI with something like TeamViewer at the same time? Do I need a usb to either net adapter to connect it to the lan after it makes the WiFi connection to the monocular? What software do you suggest to get the data from T-Vision back to the cities? Next steps? assuming the RasPi can even handle the video data stream. Thank you for trying to tackle this.

Comment: Apple... yeah, no, that ain't gonna work. RasPi itself can handle video streaming, and current versions do have both LAN and WiFi in-built. Android phone is just another computer running Android OS, so if a RasPi with LineageOS can access Google Store it might be able to install the store apps. One solution for remotely viewing an Android device desktop is setting up a VNC server with DroidVNC-NG, which is accessed with a VNC client. But honestly ... I hope I could actually help you further. I just picked this up as it smells like wildlife watching, and piqued my interest...

Comment: ... especially since nobody else seems interested. To me this is primarily an intellectual excercise. Another reason for putting in an answer is that it might jolt someone else "Wow what a stupid answer, this person has no idea what he's talking about, let's correct" :-) I sincerely hope you can get this working. I even tried to find an appropriate reddit but unfortunately wasn't successful.

Comment: Thanks for trying